# Thin p+ side in photodiode

Tags: photodiode, pn-junction

The diagram of the photodiode is shown below. Why is the p+ layer very thin here? Could we have used a n+p configuration instead? [image]

Comment: The light has to reach the depletion region to cause any effect. That's why the p+ layer has to be thin enough to let enough light through.

Comment: @Janka: could we have used a n+p configuration in which the n+ side was thin? Is there a proper reason behind keeping the p+ side on the illumination side?